# problem facing with date format in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am running query which takes input from a form and gives the output.

My input value are `datefrom  = 2021-07-03` `dateto = 2021-07-30` `stationerytype = A4 WHITE REAM`

But this query not giving me out put.

My table is
[image: Table]Structure of my table is [![table structure][image: Table Structure]

My query does not give any output.I am not getting the value of  totalrecd

I suspect the problem may be with the format of date. My orderdate column is `VARCHAR` and i can not change this column.

My code goes as follows-

```
$stationerytype=$_POST[stationerytype];
    $datefrom=$_POST[datefrom];
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(stationeryqtyrecd) AS totalrecd FROM tblstationerystock WHERE stationerytype = :stationerytype AND orderdate<:datefrom"; 
    $query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
    $query->bindValue(':stationerytype', $stationerytype, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':orderdate', $orderdate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $totalrecd = $query->fetchColumn();
    <td class="center"><?php echo $totalrecd;?></td>
```

Comment: Shouldn't stationarytype and datefrom be variables in the sql query? Also, sanitize inputs

Comment: According to the screenshot of your table structure your `orderdate` column is of type `date`, yet your comments in your question suggest `varchar`. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

There was syntax error  the correct code is -
$stationerytype=$_POST[stationerytype];

```
$datefrom=$_POST[datefrom];
$sql = "SELECT SUM(stationeryqtyrecd) AS totalrecd FROM tblstationerystock WHERE stationerytype = '$stationerytype' AND orderdate<'$datefrom'"; 
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->bindValue(':stationerytype', $stationerytype, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':orderdate', $orderdate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$totalrecd = $query->fetchColumn();
<td class="center"><?php echo $totalrecd;?></td>
```